# Enlarge Linux Disk and Extend LVM partition

Tags: centos, lvm

I have this situation in my VM Cloud Server:

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 215GB
Sector size (logical/phisycal): 512B/512B
 

Number  Start   End    Size         Type     File system  Flag
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB       primary  ext4         boot
 2      525MB   10,7GB  10,2GB      primary               lvm
 3      10,7GB  85,9GB  75,2GB      primary               lvm
```

Is it possible to expand the 75GB partition in order to se all the space (the total space is 215GB)?

For more details, I checked with `lsblk`:

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0   200G  0 disk 
├─sda1           8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2           8:2    0   9,5G  0 part 
│ ├─vg-lv_root 253:0    0  77,4G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg-lv_swap 253:1    0   2,1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─sda3           8:3    0   190G  0 part 
  └─vg-lv_root 253:0    0  77,4G  0 lvm  /
```

The sda3 should be increased in order to use all the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Your upper output does not agree with the output of `lsblk`, so one of them must be wrong about the current situation.

Not sure what generated the upper output, but seeing it even has a typo: maybe rather believe `lsblk` output.

In the case `lsblk` is right: you're done.

You can run `pvresize /dev/sda3` to make sure the LVM PV is filling the whole partition. Check `vgs` for the amount of free space in your LVM volume group.

Answer (score 0):

I solved (by asking to chatGPT :) ) who asked me to run first `pvscan`

```
# pvscan 
  PV /dev/sda2   VG vg              lvm2 [<9,51 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sda3   VG vg              lvm2 [<70,00 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [79,50 GiB] / in use: 2 [79,50 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

*Thank you for providing the `pvscan` output. It appears that both physical volumes (/dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3) are recognized, but there is no free space within the volume group (`vg`) yet.*

*To make the free space from the resized /sda3 partition available within the volume group, you can follow these steps:*

1. **Resize the Physical Volume (PV)**:

   *The physical volume (/dev/sda3) is currently larger than the allocated space within the volume group (`vg`). You need to resize the physical volume to make the additional space available:*

   ```bash
   pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 79.50GiB /dev/sda3
   ```

   *This command resizes the physical volume to match the allocated size within the volume group (`vg`).*
2. **Verify the Volume Group**:

   *Check the volume group again using the `vgdisplay` command to confirm that the additional space is now recognized:*

   ```bash
   vgdisplay
   ```

   *Look for the "Free PE / Size" field to ensure that the additional space is now available.*
3. **Extend the Logical Volume (LV)**:

   *Now that the volume group shows free space, you can proceed to extend the logical volume (`lv_root`) using the `lvextend` command:*

   ```bash
   lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg/lv_root
   ```
4. **Resize the File System**:

   *Finally, resize the file system to utilize the newly allocated space:

   - If you are using an ext4 file system, use the `resize2fs` command:*

     ```bash
     resize2fs /dev/vg/lv_root
     ```

   *If you are using a different file system (e.g., XFS), you may need to use a different command specific to that file system.
   After completing these steps, your logical volume should be expanded to use the entire available space, and your file system should reflect the increased size. Verify this using the `df -h` command.*